# illuminate/config v5.8.4 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am running `composer install` command to install all the packages dependency written in my **composer.json** file.

This is my **composer.json** file :

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "cartalyst/sentinel": "2.0.*",
    "pingpong/modules": "~2.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*",
    "elasticquent/elasticquent": "1.0.5",
    "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~6.0",
    "oriceon/toastr-5-laravel": "dev-master",
    "proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation": "~1.3.1",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0",
    "intervention/image": "^2.3",
    "spatie/laravel-analytics": "^1.4",
    "ipunkt/laravel-analytics": "^1.2",
    "davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs": "^3.0",
    "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.7.0",
    "barryvdh/laravel-snappy": "^0.3.1"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Modules\\": "modules/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan optimize",
        "php artisan vendor:publish --provider=\"Proengsoft\\JsValidation\\JsValidationServiceProvider\" --tag=public --force"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "platform": {
        "ext-mongo": "1.6.16"
    }
}
}
```

I am getting Error:-

> illuminate/config v5.8.4 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version
>   (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement.

and

> Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.46

Please look in to the picture what i am doing is :

```
Problem 1
- illuminate/config v5.8.4 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/config v5.8.3 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/config v5.8.2 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/config v5.8.0 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/config v5.7.9 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/config v5.7.8 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/config v5.7.7 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/config v5.7.6 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/config v5.7.5 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/config v5.7.4 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.40) does not satisfy that requirement.
Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.46
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.45
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.44
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.43
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.42
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.41
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.40
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.39
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.38
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.37
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.36
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.35
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.34
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.33
don't install illuminate/config v5.3.23|don't install laravel/framework v5.1.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.3.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.1.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.1.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.4.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.1.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.4.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.1.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.4.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.1.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.4.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.1.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.4.36|don't install laravel/framework v5.1.0
- don't install illuminate/config v5.4.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.1.0
- Installation request for laravel/framework 5.1.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.1.0, v5.1.1, v5.1.10, v5.1.11, v5.1.12, v5.1.13, v5.1.14, v5.1.15, v5.1.16, v5.1.17, v5.1.18, v5.1.19, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.21, v5.1.22, v5.1.23, v5.1.24, v5.1.25, v5.1.26, v5.1.27, v5.1.28, v5.1.29, v5.1.3, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.32, v5.1.33, v5.1.34, v5.1.35, v5.1.36, v5.1.37, v5.1.38, v5.1.39, v5.1.4, v5.1.40, v5.1.41, v5.1.42, v5.1.43, v5.1.44, v5.1.45, v5.1.46, v5.1.5, v5.1.6, v5.1.7, v5.1.8, v5.1.9]
```

Comment: Message is pretty self-explanatory: upgrade PHP version on server. Less popular option would be to install Laravel version 5.1.46. This less popular version could lead you to severe other errors since many other packages require newer version of PHP. So solution is to install latest stable PHP on server.

Comment: Before installing Laravel you should have checked the minimum server requirement here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation#server-requirements

Comment: Well what's your question? Is it how to install Laravel with an old PHP version or how to upgrade your PHP version?

Answer (score 0):

You require **PHP 7.1.3.**

Your current PHP version (5.5.9) does not satisfy some package of that requirement.

Apart from this, PHP 5.5 has been [unsupported](http://php.net/eol.php) for 2 years.